# Opening pdf of sd card in webview

Tags: java, android, webview, pdfrenderer

i am trying to load pdf in webview from my sdcard but it gives message
"**Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists!**"

i also googled this but after banging my head a lot i got nothing than this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926746/is-it-possible-to-open-pdf-file-store-in-sdcard-cache-in-webview) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613505/how-to-open-local-pdf-file-in-webview-in-android?rq=1) ...

```
  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_compontent);
   fill_form = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fill_form);

   fill_form.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Progress", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});


   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
   webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  // webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);        
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            progDailog.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;                
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            progDailog.dismiss();
        }
    });
 //   String fileurl = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +"pk.pdf";
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"pk.pdf");
    Uri fileurl = (Uri.fromFile(file));

    String Url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + fileurl;
    webView.loadUrl(Url);
}
```

Please give any idea how to do this ?(I don't want to use any payable rendering library.)

Comment: Unlike iPhone android 's webkit is not that strong, that it can open a PDF file. You need to use a third party library to open a PDF doc. I would recommend MuPDF library for viewing PDF files on android platform.

Comment: this post help me https://stackoverflow.com/a/43087727/2416823. It works offline, without google pdf viewer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that webview can load a pdf for you. Sso you still have two options:
1. Try to ask other applications to view this PDF for you.
2. You can try this librarry https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview if GNU policy suits you.

Comment: :( but tats the thing i wanted to do :(

Comment: You can try contact google regarding this issue on WebView and ask them to include it in future releases. But you can try Library I have suggested its free on terms of GNU.